# How to check whether input box has same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to `javascript` and `jquery`.
I have a **form** which has only one **text box** and **type is email** and I have a **submit button**. After clicking the submit button value in text box will not disappear and I don't want to(Not clearing form). Now my problem is **Button should disable after clicking on it and it should active only value in text box changes.**

My code is

```
  <input autocomplete="off" type="email" name="email" id="g-email" class="form-control required order" placeholder="Email address">

  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-default" id="messageButton" value="Place Order" onclick="$(this).attr('disabled', true);">Send message</button></div>
```

And jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name='email']").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() != $(this).val())
    {
       $("input[name='submit']").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have a start value for your input? You want to enable submit button if it changes from what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `messageButton` disabled initially and listen for the `keyup` event in the `g-email` input. Then, if the input `g-email` has text enable the button else disabled it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#g-email').on('keyup', function(){
    if($(this).val()){
      $("#messageButton").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $("#messageButton").attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" type="email" name="email" id="g-email" class="form-control required order" placeholder="Email address">

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-default" id="messageButton" value="Place Order" onclick="$(this).attr('disabled', true);" disabled='disabled'>Send message</button></div>
```

Comment: @Ash Glad to help you

Comment: Also this surely works, one could add a case for changes done without keyboard. Just to have it complete.

Answer (score 3):

Because following statement `$(this).val() != $(this).val()` will always be false.

You don't need to do this because `change` function already does what you need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#g-email').on('input', function(){
        $("button[name='submit']").removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Working example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#g-email').on('input', function(){
     $("button[name='submit']").removeAttr('disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" type="email" name="email" id="g-email" class="form-control required order" placeholder="Email address">

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-default" id="messageButton" value="Place Order" onclick="$(this).attr('disabled', true);" disabled='disabled'>Send message</button></div>
```

Comment: What if he adds a char and then he delete it? This would enable the submit button even thought it shoudn't..

Comment: @Yuri, the button has own onclick trigger function attached. Since we add a char and then delete it there are 2 states of the input

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut this depends whether he wants to check if value changed from its initial value..

Comment: @Ash, please have a look now. There was a mistake from your question.  `$("input[name='submit']")` must be changed to `$("button[name='submit']")`

Comment: @Yuri, I updated my answer. There was a mistake from question.

Comment: @Ash, you don't need to write additional condition statements or another trigger events like in others answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `.prop()` method to change submit button `disabled` value:

```js
var submit = $("#messageButton");
var input  = $("#g-email");

input.on("keyup", function(ev) {
  
  var isDisabled = submit.data("submitted") && submit.data("submitted") === input.val();
  submit.prop("disabled", isDisabled);

});

submit.on("click", function(ev) {

  submit.prop("disabled", true);
  submit.data("submitted", input.val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" type="email" name="email" id="g-email" class="form-control required order" placeholder="Email address">
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-default" id="messageButton" value="Place Order" onclick="$(this).attr('disabled', true);">Send message</button>
```

Comment: You miss the check on value changed (from original value I guess)

Comment: Thanks @Yuri, I added it.